# Why can't nosetests find one the elements in sys.path?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests, pythonpath

I have a series of unit tests that I'm running with **nose**. For some of my tests, I'd like to remove a module's path from the `sys.path` so there is no conflict with what I am testing.

```
sys.path.remove('/path/to/remove/from/sys/path')
```

If I run the Python interpreter and call `sys.path`, the `'/path/to/remove/from/sys/path'` is there in the list. However, once nosetests is called, the above code cannot find it and gives me a "not found in list" error.

Why is **nose** not able to find the path in `sys.path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script, get_mod_py_path.py, to set the PYTHONPATH. In this case, it is dropping the conflicted path.

```
import os
import sys

# Remove the global Python modules from the PYTHONPATH.
path = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
if os.environ['GLOB_PY_MODULES'] in path: 
    path.remove(os.environ['GLOB_PY_MODULES'])

# Construct the new path and print it. 
path = ':'.join(path)
print path
```

Then use it in a bash that calls nosetests.

```
PYTHONPATH=`python get_mod_py_path.py`   
nosetests --verbosity=1 --with-gae --where="../tests/unit" --gae-application="../app"
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you mean this?

```
sys.path.remove('/path/to/remove/from/sys/path')
```

If *nose* can't find it in `sys.path` then it wasn't there...  *nose* does lots of diddling with `sys.path` on its own.  Why not print `sys.path` and see what it actually is when run under *nose*

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I've edited the question. I also printed several iterations of testing in nose and Eclipse, but I didn't see the pattern as to when certain paths were included or excluded. Right now, I've created a simple script to set the PYTHONPATH before running nosetests.