# How can keep my libraries , modules or jar files Synced across diff projects

Tags: java, php, python, linux, synchronization

I am doing various projects acroos diff computers , servers and diff languages like php python java etc.

Now on every computer i have to install / download various supporting libraries like javascript libraries for PHP , Jar files for Java and many python modules.

Is there way so that i can make online folder on server with only libraries and then automatically sync them across different computers. There may be some solution out there for this but i don't know it

For java and php there is no need to install them but i don't know whether python modules or libraraies work this way or not like south, PIL, matolib etc.

Is there any thing which can help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe get some version management on the job, which is synced to the server e.g. [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Comment: I feel like i should beat my head with hammer. i am trying so much to stay away from source control and github and every now and then i see them. I am not able to yet understand how they work

Comment: @bidu: I'm not sure I agree that source control is the best way to manage the external libraries you need, but not using it for your *own* source is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Yep there's a debate to be had about whether the external dependencies should be stored in version management or not, but without setting something up (e.g. Maven) or writing some syncing scripts to suck in your dependencies, then I think version management is probably an effective solution in your case.  I'd drop the hammer @bidu and get to help.github.com - setting up version management is worth the investment and, while it might look like hassle, it really is quite straightforward once you spend an hour or two understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking planetjones version management idea (GIT or SVN), and pairing that up with scripts to setup the required libraries in your environment. If you've different python environments - I found this interesting: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: Also related (at least for python) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914289/developing-and-using-the-same-python-on-the-same-computer

Answer (score 0):

For Java projects, you could give Maven a try, and configure you own repository on your server. Don't know if it can be used for the other languages, however.